# Passing edited value from recycler view to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with an editext. Initially these textviews will contain some strings, passed from the activityto the adapter. The user can edit the values of some/all of these edit texts. Now, how do I get back this data into my activity?

My code:

```java
//Adapter class

public class AlarmAdapter {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> dates;
    private ItemClickListener mListener;

    public AlarmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dates) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //normal code
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            String date = dates.get(position);
            holder.mTxtTimeLayout.setText(date);
            holder.mTxtTimeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            //display timepicker, set the value of textview to user selected time
            holder.mTxtTimeLayout.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));

           }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dates.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView mTxtTimeLayout;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTxtTimeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeLayout);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: It'd probably help if you could show a [mcve] of your code

Comment: you can use interface

Comment: You can use ViewModel from Architecture components. It's designed to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly Create an Interface(Java Class) Like this..

```
public interface EditTextChage {
    void editText1Changes(String newText);
    void editText2Changes(String newText2);
    --------so on the others ------
}
```

> Secondly implement the interface created in the activity like that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements EditTextChanges{

   --- all other functions ---
@Override
    public void editText1Changes(String newText1) {
        //do whatever you like with text from edit text 1
    }
@Override
    public void editText2Changes(String newText2) {
        //do whatever you like with text from edit text 2
    }

}
```

> Thirdly in recyclerview's adapter's constructor add a new parameter
>   editTextChange Then your recyclerView's adapter's constructor should
>   look like this

```
private EditTextChange editTextChange;
public YourAdapter(String parameter1,--other parameter--, EditTextChange editTextChange){
--other definition ---
this.editTextChange = editTextChange;
}
```

> Then in your activity while set adapter add other parameter and in the
>   position of editTextChange just pass "this"
>
> Lastly use the following method in recyclerview's bindHolder method

```
customView.yourEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(EditText target,Editable s) {

                editTextChange.editText1Changes(target.getText.toString();
            }


        });
```

Comment: I tried using this method. But now, it returns only edited textvalues. In my case, the user can choose to leave textviews unedited.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using static variables in this type of situation.

First create a class and declare a static variable .

```
public class Utils {public static ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>(); }
```

After that in the Constructor of your Adapter

```
public AlarmAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dates) {
    this.context = context;
    Utils.dates = dates;
}
```

Now you can use this value throughout your application.

Depending upon your requirement, you might want to call

```
Utils.dates.clear();
```

in the onDestroy() method of your activity .